# python different for-loop implement get different speed and even in contrast with cache mechanism in C

Tags: python, c, caching

I learn about caching recently and knowing that it can optimize the program by improve the probability to hit the cache. And there is a piece of code that can get different time in C.

```
a[100][5000]=...//initialize
for(i=0; i<100; i=i+1) {
  for(j=0; j<5000; j=j+1) {
    a[i][j] = 2 * a[i][j];
  }
}


a[100][5000]=...//initialize
for(i=0; i<100; i=i+1) {
  for(j=0; j<5000; j=j+1) {
    a[i][j] = 2 * a[i][j];
  }
}
```

The below one is faster than above one. But in python get different result in below code.The principle is below one can hit the cache in cache Line but above one should visit the mem more frequently.

```
arr1 = [[i for i in range(5000)] for j in range(100)]
arr2 = [[i for i in range(5000)] for j in range(100)]
def test1():
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(5000):
        for j in range(100):
            arr1[i][j] = 2 * arr1[i][j]

def test2():
    start = time.time()
    sum = 0
    for j in range(100):
        for i in range(5000):
            arr2[i][j] = 2 * arr2[i][j]
%timeit -n100 test1() 
%timeit -n100 test2()
# 1.16 s ± 67.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# 1.5 s ± 101 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I wonder if the cache mechanism is diff in this two program language and the basic python is implemented by C?

Comment: The C compiler may have noticed that the two arrays have mutually exclusive lifetimes, so it reuses the same memory for both of them.

Comment: @Barmar what confused me most is why the python code in contrast.. the column cache Line ?

Comment: Python is interpreted, C is compiled, so there's lots of room for differences in behavior.

Comment: Furthermore, a Python list is **not a primitive array* and the performance characteristics are different. A CPython list is essentially an array of Py_object pointers. And *everything in Python is an object* including `int` objects.